# Differentiably redundant functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a differentiably redundant function of order 6 from the following.

(a) $e^{-x} + e^{-x/ 2} \cos({\sqrt{3x} \over 2})$

(b) $e^{-x} + \cos(x)$

(c) $e^{x/2}\sin({\sqrt{3x} \over 2})$

I know that (b) has order 4, but I cannot solve for (a) and (c).
It would be a huge waste of time if I took the derivatives and calculate them, so there must be a simple way to solve this.

According to the book, it is related to $1/2 \pm i\sqrt{3} /2$, but why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Differentiably redundant function of order $n$" is not a standard mathematical term: this is something that GRE Math authors made up for this particular problem.

> Define a function $f(x)$ to be differentiably redundant of order $n$ if the $n$th derivative $f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)$ but $f^{(k)}(x)\ne f(x)$ when $k<n$. Which of the following functions is differentiably redundant of order $6$?

By the way, this is not a shining example of mathematical writing: "when $k<n$" should be "when $0<k<n$" and, more importantly, $\sqrt{3x}$ was meant to be $\sqrt{3}x$ in both (A) and (C). This looks like a major typo in [the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=GHdsHn4vAvIC&lpg=PA75&ots=okN_hxXjaD&dq=differentiably%20redundant&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=differentiably%20redundant&f=false).

If you are familiar with complex numbers, the appearance of both $-1/2$ and $\sqrt{3}/2$ in the same formula is quite suggestive, especially since both exponential and trigonometric functions appear here. Euler's formula  $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ should come to mind. Let $\zeta=-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$: then

$$e^{-x/2}\cos \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2} = \operatorname{Re}e^{\zeta x},\qquad e^{-x/2}\sin \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2} = \operatorname{Im}\, e^{\zeta x}$$

Differentiating $n$ times, you get the factor of $\zeta^n$ inside of $\operatorname{Re}$ and $\operatorname{Im}$. Then you should ask yourself: what is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that   $\zeta^n=1$? [Helpful article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was confused by the sqrt(3x) because the period was not 2pi anymore, so it looked much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

it is obvious that e^(-1) is of order 2
exp(-x/2)cos(sqrt(3)/2 x) is corresponding to -1/2+-sqrt(3)/2, which are 3rd roots of unity (see ODE textbooks for the general solution of homogeneous linear ODE of high orders), and they generate a cyclic group that contains all 3rd roots of unity.
For A, lcm(2,3)=6, so its order is 6.
For B, lcm(2,4)=4, so its order is 4.
For C, exp(x/2)sin(sqrt(3)/2 x) is corresponding to 1/2+-sqrt(3)/2, which are 6th roots of unity, are the generators of cyclic group that contains all of 6th roots of unity. So its order is 6.